# Deploy Rails app anywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, mod-rails

How can I deploy my Rails apps anywhere in the world (including my shared hosting http://www.moxo.cz/)?
I tried **Heroku**, but I had problem with moving my dev db.
Then I found **mod_rails** and it seems I can finally put my app on mydomain.net/railsapp but it's probably impossible to deploy on shared hostings.
If I built Rails app for my client how would I deploy it on his "plain" hosting or anywhere else?
I have no experience with that and it's getting desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is a very easy option. In a plain server you usually have a ruby stack preinstalled, your provider should provide documentation about it, if you don't have a stack preinstalled you will have  to install all stack yourself which is a lot of effort.

I would recommend you to try again Heroku, you could post your problem here in SO.

mod_rails is a plugin also easy to use when you have al the stack preinstalled and preconfigured. EC2 is a good option for this. Although is not as simple is this is written, you have to find and use a preconfigured stack which usually is not a problem.

I suppose you have a provider in mind, but this is the general flow.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying "ruby stack"?
Czech Republic hostings in here don't provide Rails support, I need perfect, reliable and simple to use solution so I can deploy Rails app to MYDOMAIN.NET/myapp and have static pages on index at MYDOMAIN.NET besides it.
Since shared hostings don't provide Rails support neither option to add it because there's no possibility to change Apache config etc.
And if I look at Heroku custom domain, of course I need to change DNS to their servers, but no option to put my app on MYDOMAIN.NET/myapp https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: 1. You buy your domain, 2. you point your domain to heroku address from panel your hosting provider gives you.

Comment: I forgot 0. you need to have your application in Heroku running.
And, with Ruby stack I mean the set of tools you usually use for developing Rails applications, so it's better to call it Ruby on Rails stack, these tools are for my case: Git, Ruby, Rails, Ruby Gems

Comment: Oh right. Last night I successfully point app-name-somenumbers.herokuapp.com to rails-app-my-subdomain.my-domain.net.
I just add CNAME record and told my heroku app about its new (sub)domain and it works. My webpage on domain's root remains untouched, just like I wanted.
How many (sub)domains can be linked with Heroku apps?

Comment: 1. I think you can have as many Heroku free apps as you want. 2. I think you can have as many subdomains as you want 3. you can link them  as you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Heroku** is a simple setup formula, For a **shared host** ROR Deployment Found a good reference : **[REFERENCE LINK](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails)** this will help to deploy ROR App on a shared host.*(some modules may not be allowed on a shared server environment. You may have to go for a VPS to meet all the requirements).*